# Both workbook "freezes" when updating the first (xlsm) while the second (xlsx) is open

Tags: excel, vba

**The problem**

I have a workbook (A) which includes some macros as well as being linked to another Excel-file (data source). The workbook works perfectly and without problems if I only have this individual workbook open. If I open another random xlsx-file everything looks OK at first. But as soon as I make any updates whatsoever (e.g. pressing F2 in an empty cell and then enter) in workbook A, both workbooks seems to freeze. I can still close the workbooks in a normal procedure and the macro-button in workbook A works fine (and will trigger the macro), but I'm unable to change tabs in wb A and the tabs in the second workbook disappears. I can see the cursor, but the green Excel-border/box around target-cells are gone in both workbooks. I am also unable to update any of the cells in the workbooks...

**What I've tried**

I have tried to;

- remove all data source connections
- remove all macros (one by one, but problem still exist without any macros in wb A...)
- go through the macros to see if they causes any errors (which they don't as far as I can see)
- two other xlsm-files (unrelated to wb A) does not cause this type of error
- i've tried to use application.ScreenUpdating = False, .EnableEvents = False, .Calculation = xlCalculationManual, and setting them back to original values at the end.

**Code**

-Range("B4") is a dropdown-list without blanks. The following macro lies in Sheet1:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ApplicationON:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       Call conditionalFormatting.conditionalFormatting

ApplicationON:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

-The following macro lies in a module called "conditionalFormatting":

```
Sub conditionalFormatting()

    On Error GoTo ApplicationON:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim DASHBOARD   As Worksheet
    Dim rng1        As Range
    Dim rng2        As Range
    Dim cel         As Range
    Dim col1        As Integer
    Dim col2        As Integer

    Set DASHBOARD = Sheets("DASHBOARD")
    Set rng1 = Range("R15:R45")
    Set rng2 = Range("R15:Z45")
    col1 = 18
    col2 = 26

    With rng2
        .Cells.Font.Bold = False
        .Cells.Font.Italic = False
        .Cells.Font.Size = 11
    End With

    For Each cel In rng1
        Select Case cel.Value

        Case _
        "Case1", _
        "Case2"
            Range(Cells(cel.Row, col1), Cells(cel.Row, col2)).Font.Bold = True

        Case _
        "Case3", _
        "Case4"
           Range(Cells(cel.Row, col1), Cells(cel.Row, col2)).Font.Size = 8

        Case _
        "Case5", _
        "Case6"
           Range(Cells(cel.Row, col1), Cells(cel.Row, col2)).Font.Italic = True

       End Select
    Next  

ApplicationON:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

-The following macro lies in a module called "ExportToPDF" and has a button in worksheet "DASHBOARD" (sheet1):

```
Sub ExportToPDF()

    On Error GoTo ApplicationON:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim pt As Range

    dateStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")
    workbookPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    workbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    file_Name = dateStamp & "_" & Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("A1") & ".pdf"
    filePath = workbookPath & file_Name

    With Worksheets("DASHBOARD").PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "A6:O42"
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With

    Set pt = 
  Worksheets("DASHBOARD").Range(Worksheets("DASHBOARD").PageSetup.PrintArea)

    pt.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=filePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
          & filePath

ApplicationON:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

**After some additional testing**

It seems it has to do with looping and module Workbook_change + my dropdown-list which does not include any blank values. But still strange that it works perfectly without any other wb open, but only becomes a problem when opening an additional wb. Can't see that the code is running either when both wbs freezes...

1) made a copy and removed the data connections (so it doesn't interfere), and saving and closing the workbook

2) Opening the workbook (without any of the errorHandling and application-statement) without make any changes/updates in the spreadsheets, and opening a second file (slsx) - error occur

3) Opening the workbook (without any of the errorHandling and application-statement) and writing "=1+1" in an random empty cell, and opening a second file (slsx) - error occur

4) Opening the workbook (without any of the errorHandling and application-statement) and changing the dropdown-list once (calling the worksheet_change macro), and opening a second file (slsx) - error occur

5) Opening the workbook (in original state as posted) without making any changes/updates in the spreadsheets, and opening a second file (slsx) - error occur

6) Opening the workbook (in original state as posted) and writing "=1+1" in an random empty cell, and opening a second file (slsx) - error does not occur

7) Opening the workbook (in original state as posted) and changing the dropdown-list once (calling the worksheet_change macro), and opening a second file (slsx) - error occur

8) If I insert a blank value in the drop-downlist (workbook in original state as posted) and selecting the blank value, and opening a second file (slsx) - error does not occur

9) Selecting a value in dropdown-list - error occur

8) Removing the ExportToPDF- and conditionalFormatting-modules, and including proposed adjustment to Worksheet_change module (i.e. removing code from sheet1 and inserting it into module).

- 8.1 just opening second file without making changes to xlsm, and having value in dropdown-list - error occur
- 8.2 typing 1+1 in random empty cell - error occur
- 8.3 changing dropdown-list once (to another value) - error occur
- 8.4 changing dropdown-list to blank - error does not occur

Comment: While I don't see it, it *might* be causing an endless loop where Range("B2") gets changed by VBA (perhaps indirectly by way of a formula) which calls the Worksheet_Change() event again, which triggers the same change, which triggers the same Worksheet_Change(). To insure this isn't happening in your Worksheet_Change() event toggle off `EnableEvents` like: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then at the end toggle it back on.

Comment: when the workbook is freezing, does it look like it is running vba (with "running..." in the vba editor window caption? If so, can you try to interrupt execution with Ctrl + Pause/Break?

Comment: @JNevill - this is exactly what I was thinking too

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I forgot to include those. Please see my updated code. I Have one version with those and one without, both causing the error

Comment: Nothing in the code would trigger a `Worksheet_Change` event it seems since this event is not triggered by a cells value changing due to a formula. Your code does not physically change a cells value anywhere so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: `Set pt` is not correct, you may not see it because you have an error trap

Comment: in your worksheet_change, if the intersect condition is false, then you don't restore the application.screenupdating calculation and enable events. I would actually only set them to false,manual,false inside the if statement.

Comment: plus, do you really need to catch the error in 'worksheet_change' ? you are catching it inside conditionalFormatting.conditionalFormatting . If an error occured you probably want to be informed about it and you are suppresing it

Comment: Thank your for your replies. I have tested a bit. The code doesn't seem to run when the error occur. I tried to remove the ExportToPDF module, but error still persist. I have tried to put the application-changes inside the if-statement as well as removing them in the worksheet_change, but error still occurs. The strange part is that the code works 100% as it should (or at least as I would expect) when only the xlsm-file is open. I haven't been able to see a pattern either because sometime it actually works with another xlsx-file open, but the error appear after awhile.

Comment: The actionbar of the second worksheet is all greyed-out when it opens (if that gives any clues). Good question SNicolaou - I have done it for in some other parts of the worksheet but was unable to change the character-size with Excels conditional formatting

Comment: ok, yes it seems you need vba to change the size and font family...

Comment: does your xlsm file that causes the problem have any macro inside of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if this issue occurs after "removing all modules and clearing all macros" per the comment below, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has not been provided.

Comment: apologies for the many comments, but do you need to have both workbooks open in the same excel instance? (as a temporary workaround) can you run a new excel instance: "Windows Button + Key R" and then in the textbox enter "excel /x" and click ok. That is assuming that excel.exe is in the path environment variable. If not (you will get an error) you have to include the full path to excel.exe i.e. "C:\Somewhere\depends\onXL\version\excel.exe /x"

Comment: Just give me one sec, I'm currently testing. But what keeps this difficult is that it does not occur with other xlsm-files (with different macros obviously), it does occur with or without the application-statements, it occurs without some of the macros present.

Comment: I repeat, your `set pt` is incorrect

Comment: I have tested a bit further, see my findings in the original question/text. I suppose the loop is causing this (?). Is there a way to rewrite Workbook_change to not cause looping? I will also take the other comments into consideration! Thanks for being helpful and patient by the way!

Comment: can you add a msgbox in your error catch to see if an error occured? Place exit sub (and application.xyx = w) before "ApplicationOn:" and put "msgbox err.description" after the "ApplicationOn:" this is to check if errors are happening.

Comment: long shot  but you are referencing Sheets("Dashboard") when you got two workbooks open. You need to be sure that the Sheets("Dashboard") is referenced on the correct workbook. perhaps check if the worksheet exists before making the Set DASHBOARD = Sheets("Dashboard")

Comment: I will try, but I now tried to remove all macros (local in sheets and modules) from the wb (no macros are visible from "Macros"-button under Developer), and the error still occurs when opening another wb in addition to having a value in the dropdown-list... Setting the dropdown-list to blank and the error disappears.The same xlsx-file opens without problems using a different wb and a wb with other macros...This doesn't make sense to me... Either the error is caused by the formulas in the wb or the wb itself is broken/corrupt. I have never experienced this before.

Comment: ok, so next thing is what typical helpdesk person will tell you (apologies for any offence). Have you tried to close your excel and restart your pc? (not joking)

Comment: None taken, because its a good suggestion and usuallly it works, but I've tried it. I think I just have to create a new wb and test frequently as I rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was a mysterious error with the Excel-file. I rebuilt the dashboard and it worked as expected. To be on the safe-side I skipped the "Workbook_change"-code linked to a  filter and just used a simple button to execute the code instead. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

If you cause an error in ***any*** of these functions, you set `Application.EnableEvents = True`. So... If those are triggered from a call originating from inside an event handler, you lose your re-entry protection. You also unconditionally do this at the top of everything:

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
> Application.EnableEvents = False
> ```

That smacks of [cargo-cult behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158080/36565). You should only be performing this work where it is necessary, and close to the ***place*** where it is necessary. Whatever performance gains you think you're getting by doing this are probably just illusory. In fact, repeatedly messing with the `Application` state is probably doing more *harm* than good from a performance standpoint.

The solution is to not rely on Excel to guard re-entry into your event handler - do it manually:

```
Private reentryFlag As Boolean    'Module level

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If reentryFlag Then Exit Sub
    reentryFlag = True

    On Error GoTo Handler
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    conditionalFormatting.conditionalFormatting
Handler:
    reentryFlag = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Clearly I haven't understood the use of application-changes, and I will redo my code. But what bugs me is that even with these changes (or in fact removing all modules and clearing all macros) the error still occurs... I know its difficult to troubleshoot without having the spreadsheet, but can a Excel-file just be "broken" without giving any errors and behaving the way I'm describing? I'm using win7 (yes...) if that matters.

Comment: "can a Excel-file just be "broken" without giving any errors"....i want to say No but my experience doesn't let me :-)

Comment: @Jeff If the error occurs with no code at all, I'm not sure I understand the question.